# How to populate treeview in WinUI 3?

Tags: xaml, winui-3

I have one model named Visit

```cs
public class Visit
{
    public int {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public string VisitNo {get; set;}
    public string Details {get;set;}
}
```

How can I populate a TreeView WinUI 3 like main roots are Years and Childrens are VisitNos.

I expecting the result below.

```
+2022
  -0001
  -0002
+2023
  -0003
  -0004
  -0005
```

Comment: Can you post code for a sample data? I don't understand the items under each year.

Comment: Do you mean that you have a collection (List?) of Visists and you want to group it by Date.Year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this will do:

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace TreeViewExample;

public class Visit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string VisitNo { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Details { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public partial class YearItem : ObservableObject
{
    public YearItem(int year)
    {
        Year = year;
    }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int year;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Visit> visits = new();
}

public class TreeViewTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate? YearTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate? VisitTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate? SelectTemplateCore(object item)
    {
        return item switch
        {
            YearItem => YearTemplate,
            Visit => VisitTemplate,
            _ => throw new NotSupportedException(),
        };
    }
}

public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<YearItem> yearItems = new();

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        List<Visit> visits = new()
        {
            new Visit { Id = 1, Date = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).AddMonths(-3), VisitNo = "001", Details = "Visit 1" },
            new Visit { Id = 2, Date = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1), VisitNo = "002", Details = "Visit 2" },
            new Visit { Id = 3, Date = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2), VisitNo = "003", Details = "Visit 3" },
            new Visit { Id = 4, Date = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1), VisitNo = "004", Details = "Visit 4" },
            new Visit { Id = 5, Date = DateTime.Now, VisitNo = "005", Details = "Visit 5" }
        };

        foreach (Visit visit in visits)
        {
            if (YearItems
                .Where(x => x.Year == visit.Date.Year)
                .FirstOrDefault() is not YearItem visitsViewModel)
            {
                visitsViewModel = new(visit.Date.Year);
                YearItems.Add(visitsViewModel);
            }

            visitsViewModel.Visits.Add(visit);
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="TreeViewExample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:TreeViewExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <local:MainPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
    </Page.DataContext>

    <Page.Resources>
        <local:TreeViewTemplateSelector x:Key="TreeViewTemplateSelector">
            <local:TreeViewTemplateSelector.YearTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:YearItem">
                    <TreeViewItem
                        Content="{x:Bind Year}"
                        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Visits}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:TreeViewTemplateSelector.YearTemplate>
            <local:TreeViewTemplateSelector.VisitTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Visit">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind VisitNo}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:TreeViewTemplateSelector.VisitTemplate>
        </local:TreeViewTemplateSelector>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TreeView
            ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TreeViewTemplateSelector}"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.YearItems, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, This what I exactly want.

Comment: Great! Then can you accept the answer so we can close this section?

Comment: I already accept the answer by clicking up button. It won't show here, thanks again!